# NavigationLink don't navigate anymore after incomplete swipe from left to right

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

In my app I have a `NavigationStack` inside the `detail` of a `NavigationSplitView`. With the code below the navigation back and forward works fine but if from the detail, I incompletely swipe left to dismiss the view, the `NavigationLink` doesn't work anymore. This code is partially copied from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types).
Does anyone know what causes the problem?

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.purple, .pink, .orange]
    @State private var selection: Color? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(colors, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { color in
                NavigationLink(color.description, value: color)
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                if let color = selection {
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(color.description, value: color)
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(color)
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("Pick a color")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I've made some code improvements creating separate `struct` for each view to avoid confusion and better understand the code but the problem persist.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.purple, .pink, .orange]
    @State private var selection: Color? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(colors, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { color in
                NavigationLink(color.description, value: color)
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                if let color = selection {
                    DetailView(color: color)
                } else {
                    Text("Pick a color")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("Go to third view", value: color)
                .padding()
                .background(color)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Detail View")
        .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
            ThirdView(color: color)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ThirdView: View {
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .navigationTitle("Third View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug related to the new navigation setup, I’ve seen a few different versions of the same thing

Comment: May be the NavigationStack in the detail view is the problem : you have 2 different navigation handler working at the same time.

Comment: @PtitXav From the NavigationSplitView documentation: "You can also embed a NavigationStack in a column. Tapping or clicking a NavigationLink that appears in an earlier column sets the view that the stack displays over its root view. Activating a link in the same column adds a view to the stack. Either way, the link must present a data type for which the stack has a corresponding navigationDestination(for:destination:) modifier.".

Comment: Did not know. In your code, both navigation link seem identical. May this confuse the system ?

Comment: @PtitXav In my opinion it's a bug, because the navigation works fine until the user don't complete the swipe. This is not a common scenario but can happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug is fixed. At least it works as expected on the latest Xcode 14.1 RC.